# How to add new - blank slide at the end of .pptx file using OpenXml?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml

I want to insert a new slide - blank slide at the end of the .pptx file using OpenXml.
can anyone have any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly write some code to achieve this using Open Xml sdk for Powerpoint. But the simplest way to do this programatically is to use [Presentation Builder](http://powertools.codeplex.com/downloads/get/602330) a nice wrapper around open xml to work with powerpoint presentations.

Create a powerpoint presentation file with a single blank slide. Use Presentation builder to append it to all your files. Watch [this video](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2013/01/14/quick-introduction-to-presentationbuilder.aspx) to get started.

Hope this helps.